# Multiple items to render in EJS

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am new to we programming. I got stuck with rendering JavaScript variables.

Could you please give me an advice to resolve?

Inside `.ejs`, I am trying to iterate over table

```
      <tr>
        <% bodies.forEach(function(body){ %>
          <% try (typeof body.rowNum !== 'undefined') { %>
            <th scope="row"><%= body.rowNum %></th>
            <% if(typeof body.tick !== 'undefined') { %>
              <td><%= body.tick %></td>
            <% } %>
            <% if(typeof body.exDiv !== 'undefined') { %>
              <td><%= body.exDiv %></td>
            <% } %>
            <% if(typeof body.divYield !== 'undefined') { %>
              <th><%= body.divYield %></th>
            <% } %>
            <% if(typeof body.qty !== 'undefined') { %>
              <th><%= body.qty %></th>
            <% } %>
            <% if(typeof body.total !== 'undefined') { %>
              <th><%= body.total %></th>
            <% } %>
          <% } %>
        <% }) %>
      </tr>
```

Below is `.js` file:

```
app.post("/", function(req, res){
   var bodies = {rowNum: 1, tick: tick, exDiv: exDiv, divYield: dividend, qty: 50, total: total}
   res.render("list", {bodies:bodies});
});
```

The error message I am getting

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token '(' in C:\Users\yoonl\Desktop\DividendTracker\views\list.ejs while compiling ejs

If the above error is not helpful, you may want to try EJS-Lint:
https://github.com/RyanZim/EJS-Lint
Or, if you meant to create an async function, pass `async: true` as an option.
at new Function ()
at Template.compile (C:\Users\yoonl\Desktop\DividendTracker\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:661:12)
at Object.compile (C:\Users\yoonl\Desktop\DividendTracker\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:396:16)
at handleCache (C:\Users\yoonl\Desktop\DividendTracker\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:233:18)
at tryHandleCache (C:\Users\yoonl\Desktop\DividendTracker\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:272:16)
at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (C:\Users\yoonl\Desktop\DividendTracker\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:489:10)
at View.render (C:\Users\yoonl\Desktop\DividendTracker\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
at tryRender (C:\Users\yoonl\Desktop\DividendTracker\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
at Function.render (C:\Users\yoonl\Desktop\DividendTracker\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\yoonl\Desktop\DividendTracker\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1012:7)

**[Question] I am not familiar with `async` if the following issue can be fixed by adding async function, could you please share an example how to use it?**

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The are a few things you need to fix..

1.) you are expecting an `array` in your template, since you use `bodies.forEach(...)` but you pass an object. Fix this by doing:

```
var bodies = [{rowNum: 1, tick: 123, exDiv: 123, divYield: 123, qty: 50, total: 123}];
res.render("list", {bodies}); // use Object Property Value Shorthand instead of {bodies:bodies}
```

2.) `<% try (typeof body.rowNum !== 'undefined') { %>`
This is incorrect syntax, I think you wanted to use `if` instead:

```
<% if (typeof body.rowNum !== 'undefined') { %>
```

Your error has nothing to do with `async` in this case - it's just incorrect syntax and incorrect data passed to the template

Comment: Yes!! thank you for your explanation! I have a better understanding now!